# Why isn't there a unary operator to get a multiplicative inverse? 0-x = -x ... 1/x =?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

In C/C++ there is a unary minus operator, which returns the additive inverse of an arithmetic type (at least in most cases), i.e.

```
int x = 2, y = 2;
assert(x + (-x) == 0);
```

From a mathematical viewpoint it doesn't matter if one writes -x or 0-x, but from a programmer perspective it does. The sequence of instructions used to evaluate -x is in general different than the sequence of instructions used to evaluate 0-x! Having a unary minus operator in C++ does actually make sense despite being just syntactic sugar. So does a unary operator returning the multiplicative inverse, doesn't it? But why does C++ (like many (most?all?) languages) lack such an operator?

EDIT:

My main point is, that calculating an inverse of a number x (additive or multiplicative) does not require neutral elements (0 or 1 respectively) being processed by the computer. In fact 0 and 1 are non trivial entities for computers. While evaluating 0.0-x or 1.0/x is rather "simple" (precision is still a big problem here) for floating types (like float or double in C), it can become quite complex in general. Like for muti. precision floating point types 0.0-x is way more complex than -x and thus -x is not just handy but also generates more efficient code. On the other hand one has to introduce a function like inv(x) or x.inv() or whatever to achieve the same for multiplication (multiplicative inverse), instead of maybe just writing /x for 1.0/x ... Afaik the lack of such an operator is not only observable in C and C++ but in many other languages even in languages primarily designed for math which gets me puzzled ;)

Comment: "The sequence of instructions used to evaluate -x is in general different than the sequence of instructions used to evaluate 0-x!" - you seem to be stuck in the 80's without optimizing compilers.

Comment: As to the actual question: because there's no such convention in maths either (so it was not evident/worth it to invent such an operator). I personally don't know if there even exists such a notation; I've never encountered it yet.

Comment: And also, I think you're talking about "additive inverse", not "multiplicative inverse" (as your title suggests)

Comment: The answer to every question of the form "why wasn't this feature included in [my favorite programming language]" is always the same: the benefit did not outweigh the cost.

Comment: @vsoftco no, read the question.

Comment: @user3477950 aahhh ok, got it, the main reason is that you don't really need such an operator. Just write it as 1/x, you have 3 chars to write, cannot be simpler than that. Also, sometimes (in a module or ring) you may not have a non-multiplicative inverse, and all hell breaks loose. I see absolutely no advantage of having a notation for this.

Comment: In math, there isn't a unary reciprocal operator either. You have to say either `1/x` or `x^(-1)`.

Comment: @Mysticial: The `x^(-1)` notation (can't do superscripts in comments) can loosely be thought of as a postfix operator.

Comment: @user3477950: In 1984, division was unity, unicode was ascii, and 64kB was enough.

Comment: @KerrekSB And probably `0 - x` and `-x` translated into different machine code. Not so much today.

Answer (score 5):

Because there is no unary multiplicative inverse symbol in mathematics.

You either represent it as `x^-1` or `1/x` both of which can be down (albeit in a roundabout way for power) in C++ as well.

Unary negation only exists because it exists in mathematics.

Comment: $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:x':=x^{-1}$ In math everything is a symbol ... especially $x^{-1}$ and $1/x$. One can easily come up with a simple to type (one character) symbol like x' or whatever.

Comment: @livingissuicide: But _why_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe for the same reason there is operator - () I guess - I don't know that is why I ask ;)

Comment: The bitwise operators do not exist mathematically, either. I would presume that unary negation only exists because it's a natural extension of writing negative numbers, whereas unary division has no natural analog.

Comment: @livingissuicide: That is different, unary negation is a well established standard that is recognizable. Heck even Haskell includes it at great pain to the compiler. In contrast what you are suggesting is a unique symbol backed into the compiler. The feature cost of such a thing is astronomical, especially when you consider how heavily C++ overuses symbols as it is.

Comment: I wish there was an operator for "run my linear regression algorithm" in C/C++ why didn't they include it in the language damn them!

Comment: Have you got a source for this or is it just speculation?

Comment: I think it's nice that we have unary `+` in C++. It allows you 2 very easily promote any numerical value up to `int`, and convert lvalue to rvalue, by just writing `+v`. Of course this promotion plus conversion, as a simple unary `+` operator, comes from mathematics.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Speculation, but since B has unary negation I feel like referencing unary negation as an oddball is a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

[Guvante's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23923239/827263) correctly points out that there's no common mathematical notation for the multiplicative inverse (though x<sup>-1</sup> could loosely be thought of as a postfix operator).

In addition, C++ is derived from C, which is derived from [B](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/kbman.html). The B language didn't even have floating-point arithmetic.

C itself is primarily a systems programming language, which a greater emphasis on integers than on floating-point arithmetic. A multiplicative inverse operation on integers is not particularly useful. (Well, it might be useful for modular arithmetic, but C unsigned types don't behave that way.)

The set of arithmetic operators hasn't changed much from B to C to C++. I think the addition of unary `+` was the biggest change.

Furthermore, there's really no great need for a multiplicative inverse operator even for floating-point. It's easy enough to write `1.0 / x` -- and any decent compiler will generate the same code that as it would for a hypothetical inverse operator applied to `x`. (For some CPUs, that code would apply a division operator to the values `1.0` and `x` anyway.)